# Getting error 405 (Method Not Allowed) while calling POST WEBAPI from AngularJS $http?

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api

I have WEBAPI project and AngularJS client side project. $http.get calls are working fine and also $http.post calls with null data are working but with data its throwing error '405 (Method Not Allowed)'.I have enabled CORS too. Please provide solution.

I have added following things in web.config

```
 <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
     <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>



<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

This is the WEBAPI

[HttpPost]
    public bool SubmitQuesiton(JObject data)
    {
        return Factory.SubmitQuestion(data);
    }

This is AngularJS code

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:53546/api/demo/SubmitQuesiton",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: data
        })
```

Comment: Please check the internet. There are dozens of answers to this problem depending on `asp.net-web-api`.

Comment: @lin tried all searching from hours but not able to solve

Comment: So than add to your questions what you have tried right now.

Comment: Is your web API is allowed to invoke against HTTP POST?

Comment: @Pete yes webapi is HTTPPost

Comment: @Speedy please add what you have tried so far. I realy think you did not tried the solutions provided in the web right now.

Comment: can you share your implementation and the angular request?

Comment: @lin please check updated question

Comment: @Speedy Is WebDAV disabled?

Comment: @lin yes added  <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> in webconfig

Comment: @Speedy this allows me to say that you did not try all the answers provided in the web. Please check again, you will definitely find an answer which will help you. This problem has been solved many many many times. Read the other answer carefully and check the guide provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question. Issue is due CORS, it should be enabled in WEBAPI project. The CORS enabling not works through WEB.config code, you need to enable CORS through backend.

Note - remove all web.config CORS enabling code if its there in web.config i.e the below code

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Steps
1. Install CORS package Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors for WEBAPI project
2. In WebApiConfig.cs add this code

```
var corsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                               "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttribute);
```

Done.